# In Perl, can I treat a string as a byte array?

Tags: perl, string, binary

In Perl, is it appropriate to use a string as a byte array containing 8-bit data? All the documentation I can find on this subject focuses on 7-bit strings.

For instance, if I read some data from a binary file into `$data`

```
my $data;

open FILE, "<", $filepath;
binmode FILE;
read FILE $data 1024;
```

and I want to get the first byte out, is `substr($data,1,1)` appropriate? (again, assuming it is 8-bit data)

I come from a mostly C background, and I am used to passing a `char` pointer to a `read()` function. My problem might be that I don't understand what the underlying representation of a string is in Perl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bundled documentation for the `read` command, reproduced here, provides a lot of information that is relevant to your question.

`read FILEHANDLE,SCALAR,LENGTH,OFFSET`

`read FILEHANDLE,SCALAR,LENGTH`

> Attempts to read LENGTH **characters** of data into variable SCALAR
>           from the specified FILEHANDLE.  Returns the number of
>           characters actually read, 0 at end of file, or undef if there
>           was an error (in the latter case $! is also set).  SCALAR will
>           be grown or shrunk so that the last character actually read is
>           the last character of the scalar after the read.
>
> An OFFSET may be specified to place the read data at some place
>           in the string other than the beginning.  A negative OFFSET
>           specifies placement at that many characters counting backwards
>           from the end of the string.  A positive OFFSET greater than the
>           length of SCALAR results in the string being padded to the
>           required size with "\0" bytes before the result of the read is
>           appended.
>
> The call is actually implemented in terms of either Perl's or
>           system's fread() call.  To get a true read(2) system call, see
>           "sysread".
>
> Note the **characters**: depending on the status of the filehandle,
>           either (8-bit) bytes or characters are read.  **By default all
>           filehandles operate on bytes, but for example if the filehandle
>           has been opened with the ":utf8" I/O layer (see "open", and the
>           "open" pragma, open), the I/O will operate on UTF-8 encoded
>           Unicode characters, not bytes.**  Similarly for the ":encoding"
>           pragma: in that case pretty much any characters can be read.

Comment: my nature being very pedantic, when I read this in the documentation I found `character` ambiguous. I was unclear if it means a unit of data (ie, one byte) or a unit of a string (dependent on encoding)

Comment: Calling `binmode FILE, ":raw"` or `binmod FILE, ":bytes"` will always open your filehandle in "bytes" mode, regardless of your default IO layer (say, if you declared `use utf8`).

Comment: I actually agree that the use of "characters" reads like a bug to me, especially given how much attention is paid to the distinction between characters, bytes, and octets in `Encode(3perl)`.  It happens to be the right word, but I think I'd like it if it said "characters (as defined by the current I/O layer)".  I guess this is also a criticism of your answer, inasmuch as `read` always reads "characters" -- but sometimes "character" is defined as "octet" and sometimes as "UTF-8 code point".

Answer (score 2):

See [perldoc -f pack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) and [perldoc -f unpack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) for how to treat strings as byte arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [sysopen](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysopen.html) and [sysread](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysread.html) if you want to read bytes from binary file.

See also [perlopentut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html#Binary-Files).

Whether this is appropriate or necessary depends on what exactly you are trying to do.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -l

use strict; use warnings;
use autodie;

use Fcntl;

sysopen my $bin, 'test.png', O_RDONLY;
sysread $bin, my $header, 4;

print map { sprintf '%02x', ord($_) } split //, $header;
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> t
89504e47
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings are strings of "characters", which are bigger than a byte.[1](https://metacpan.org/module/Encode)  You can store bytes in them and manipulate them as though they are characters, taking `substr`s of them and so on, and so long as you're just manipulating entities in memory, everything is pretty peachy.  The data storage is weird, but that's mostly not your problem.[2](https://metacpan.org/module/open)

When you try to read and write from files, the fact that your characters might not map to bytes becomes important and interesting.  Not to mention annoying.  This annoyance is actually made a bit worse by Perl trying to do what you want in the common case:  If all the characters in the string fit into a byte and you happen to be on a non-Windows OS, you don't actually have to do anything special to read and write bytes.  Perl will complain, however, if you have stored a non-byte-sized character and try to write it without giving it a clue about what to do with it.

This is getting a little far afield, largely because encoding is a large and confusing topic.  Let me leave it off there with some references:  Look at [Encode(3perl)](https://metacpan.org/module/Encode), [open(3perl)](https://metacpan.org/module/open), [perldoc open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html), and [perldoc binmode](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html) for lots of hilarious and gory details.

So the summary answer is "Yes, you can treat strings as though they contained bytes if they do in fact contain bytes, which you can assure by only reading and writing bytes.".

[1](https://metacpan.org/module/Encode):  Or pedantically, "which can express a larger range of values than a byte, though they are stored as bytes when that is convenient".  I think.

[2](https://metacpan.org/module/open):  For the record, strings in Perl are internally represented by a data structure called a 'PV' which in addition to a character pointer knows things like the length of the string and the current value of `pos`.[3](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)

[3](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html):  Well, it will start storing the current value of `pos` if it starts being interesting.  See also

```
use Devel::Peek;

my $x = "bluh bluh bluh bluh";
Dump($x);
$x =~ /bluh/mg;
Dump($x);
$x =~ /bluh/mg;
Dump($x);
```

Answer (score 0):

It might help more if you tell us what you are trying to do with the byte array.  There are various ways to work with binary data, and each lends itself to a different set of tools.

Do you want to convert the data into a Perl array?  If so, `pack` and `unpack` are a good start.  `split` could also come in handy.

Do you want to access individual elements of the string without unpacking it?  If so, `substr` is fast and will do the trick for 8 byte data.  If you want other bit depths, take a look at the `vec` function, which treads a string as a bit vector.

Do you want to scan the string and convert certain bytes to other bytes?  Then the `s///` or `tr///` constructs might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Allow me just to post a small example about treating string as binary array - since I myself found it difficult to believe that something called "substr" would handle null bytes; but seemingly it does - below is a snippet of a perl debugger terminal session (with both string and array/list approaches):

```
$ perl -d

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.32
Editor support available.

Enter h or `h h' for help, or `man perldebug' for more help.

^D
Debugged program terminated.  Use q to quit or R to restart,
  use o inhibit_exit to avoid stopping after program termination,
  h q, h R or h o to get additional info.  

  DB<1> $str="\x00\x00\x84\x00"

  DB<2> print $str
�
  DB<3> print unpack("H*",$str) # show content of $str as hex via `unpack`
00008400
  DB<4> $str2=substr($str,2,2)

  DB<5> print unpack("H*",$str2)
8400
  DB<6> $str2=substr($str,1,3)

  DB<7> print unpack("H*",$str2)
008400

[...]

  DB<30> @stra=split('',$str); print @stra # convert string to array (by splitting at empty string)
�
  DB<31> print unpack("H*",$stra[3]) # print indiv. elems. of array as hex
00
  DB<32> print unpack("H*",$stra[2]) 
84
  DB<33> print unpack("H*",$stra[1]) 
00
  DB<34> print unpack("H*",$stra[0]) 
00
  DB<35> print unpack("H*",join('',@stra[1..3])) # print only portion of array/list via indexes (using flipflop [two dots] operator) 
008400
```